# Cannot delete address book in Audience Manager 2011

Tags: 2011-sp1

I would like to delete certain address book sin Tridion 2011 Audience Manager, however there is nu delete button available. I see no option to delete an address book. How should I go about this? It seems weird to me that I cannot remove an address book.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it needs to be done by a System Administrator within the Administration section?

Comment: Well my user had full admin rights. Where would the option to delete an address book be visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please could you:

- Login to the SDL Tridion Content Manager Explorer (GUI).
- Either from the SDL Tridion tab, or Home tab select 'Administration'.
- Expand the 'Audience Management' tab.
- Locate the Address Book you'd like to remove, right click and select 'Delete'

Comment: Neil and RJE is correct -- you can only delete Address Books from the Administration section. I would add that you cannot delete the Address Book if it is in use by Publications (and any items within said Publications) so you might need to do some clean up actions first.

Comment: WHich clean up actions would be needed?

Comment: It tells me that the address book is in use. But do I have to delete all my mailings to delete an address book? That seems like a very bad design?

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete the Mailing(s) itself. From the 'Audience Management' tab, move the Address Book(s) from the 'Allowed Address Books' section to the 'Available Address Books' section, and save the Publication.

If you're still unable to remove the Address Book it may be in use by a Mailing.  To disassociate an Address Book from a Mailing, you can go to the Mailing, and then move the Address Book from the 'Selected Address Books' section, to the 'Available Address Books' section, and Save the Mailing.   You should then be able to delete the Address Book.

Comment: If it helps, and I hope I did this right ;-) the below may help you identify to which Mailing an Address Book is associated.  You can run this against the TRIDION_CM_EMAIL database.

`SELECT MAILINGS_GROUPS.MAILING_ID
 ,MAILINGS_GROUPS.GROUP_ID
 ,GROUPS.TITLE AS 'ADDRESS BOOK'
 ,GROUPS.ID
 ,MAILINGS.TITLE AS 'MAILING TITLE'
 ,MAILINGS.PAGE_URI AS 'TcmUri of Page used in Mailing, take first number for Publication ID'
FROM MAILINGS_GROUPS
 ,GROUPS
 ,MAILINGS
WHERE MAILINGS_GROUPS.MAILING_ID = MAILINGS.ID
 AND MAILINGS_GROUPS.GROUP_ID = GROUPS.ID`